# Protobuf for communicating with legacy systems

Tags: .net-4.0, protocol-buffers, windows-xp, named-pipes, protobuf-net

I'm looking forward to use protobuf-net in conjunction with named pipes for communicating with legacy systems (WinXP 32-bit, NetFramework 4.0.3).
Happily there is at least version 2.4.6 available for Net Framework 4.0.
The readme.md in the latest version states that net20 / net35 can be targeted but is not supported greatly. Furthermore the info-page states that Net 4.6.1+ is required
and in the project-configuration we find that at least netstandard2.0 must be targeted.

Is there any (painless) chance to compile later versions of protobuf-net
for Net Framework 4.0 ?
It seems there must be substitutions for "System.Buffers" and "System.Memory",
which is likely to be a lot of work.

Furthermore from the source-code we can see that using protobuf-net with named pipes is still considered to be "experimental".
Can there any statements be made how far this is from stable ?
I would like to use protobuf-net in a productive environment like shown in [IPC using Protobuf](https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/IPC-in-net-core-using-protobuf/), which
is quite elegant solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protobuf-net v2 includes down-level targets for net20 and net35; protobuf-net v3 *does not*. For an in-depth discussion of *why*, [please see this blog post](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/01/net-core-net-5-exodus-of-net-framework.html). Could v3 hypothetically build against v2? Possibly, with suitable amounts of effort. The blog post discusses that in much more detail, though.

> The readme.md in the latest version states that net20 / net35 can be targeted

Please can you provide me with a link to that, so I can get that clarified. I've checked, and I can't see that statement.

> Furthermore from the source-code we can see that using protobuf-net with named pipes is still considered to be "experimental". Can there any statements be made how far this is from stable ?

The experimental named pipe basic RPC layer is *entirely that*: experimental; it is not considered stable, and I'll probably kill it in favour of gRPC (see also: protobuf-net.Grpc) unless I have significant reasons to add more effort. In particular, Microsoft are investing some effort into making in-process gRPC work, so it may be more pragmatic to just combine with those efforts. However! That is likely to be limited to .NET 5 (or possibly later), which doesn't help you if you're targeting .NET Framework 2.0.

Ultimately: I hate to break this to you, but: the old versions of .NET Framework are long since retired. Most library authors - and *especially* authors of free libraries - are unlikely to invest the significant effort required to properly support them.

Comment: Hello Marc. Yes you are right, I took to readme.md from v2 which states the targets net20 and net35. Killing named pipe support is very bad for my usecase therefore I consider using the original protobuf like state [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/csharp). I agree with you that it will be a significant effort for you to maintain net40 compatibility, so I thought about doing it ourselves. Thanks for your fast response

Comment: @AmbitiousD to be clear: I haven't "killed" named pipe support; it was ***never truly alive***

Comment: Yes i understand but the fact that it's likely to be killed lets me think twice if I base a new application on a feature that will probably not be available and is not near being stable. That's a pity because from your github-page I like the way protobuf-net works. Basically I'm just search for a way interface with legacy systems as I want to avoid implementing a new concept in net40.